# How to access address mapping to array struct in hardhat solidity?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, ethereumjs, unittesting

I'm writing Unit Test using hardhat for a solidity contract. There is a public mapping variable which has a mapping of address to array of struct.

```
 struct ticket {
        uint16 looteryID;
        uint ticketPrice;
        uint ticketSerialNo;
    }

mapping(address => ticket[]) public activeTickets;

function buyLottery(uint16 _id) payable public {
    activeTickets[msg.sender].push(ticket(_id,10,100));
}
```

I want to write unit test where I want to check the length of ticket array in activeTickets for msg.sender (anyone who is calling buyLottery function). I tried few hit and trail but all failed. Below is one of the attempts which failed.

Unit Test Code

```
 it("User can buy lottery",async () => { 
await lotteryInstance.connect(addr1).buyLottery(1,{value: ethers.utils.parseEther('1')});
        const userTickets = await lotteryInstance.activeTickets(addr1.address);
             expect(userTickets.length).equal(1);
             expect(userTickets[0].looteryID).equal(1);
            });
```

This will push and ticket details to activeTickets. If we assume msg.sender is 0xFe123d4 then activeTickets should have something like
0xFe123d4 => [{1,10,100}]
Now I want to test whether activeTickets was successfully updated or not, by checking current length of ticket w.r.t address 0xFe123d4 and also by accessing and comparing the pushed value.

Comment: What you mean exactly? if you explain more what is your problem probably i can help you

Comment: But it seems that your test code doesn't check anything, it just call function of your contract then log the `userTickets`

Comment: @Alireza, thanks for responding. I have updated the question with some more clarification on what exactly I want to achieve.

Comment: Your test passed or it returns error?

Comment: It returned error

Comment: Could you clarify what you *are* seeing `userTickets` as?

Comment: Actually it should be like the `0xFe123d4 => [{1,10,100}]` that yourself mentioned but try to get it using a getter function like that, for get data that may you need, try to add some getter functions. I'll write it as a answer , try this way and notify me if problem solves.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
 struct ticket {
        uint16 looteryID;
        uint ticketPrice;
        uint ticketSerialNo;
    }

mapping(address => ticket[]) public activeTickets;

function buyLottery(uint16 _id) payable public {
    activeTickets[msg.sender].push(ticket(_id,10,100));
}

function getLooteryID(uint256 index, address userAddress) external view returns(uint16) { 
   return activeTickets[userAddress][index].looteryID;
}

function getLength(address userAddress) external view returns(uint256) {
    return return activeTickets[userAddress].length;
}
```

and in the test file:

```
 it("User can buy lottery",async () => { 
const lotteryConnectedToSigner = await lotteryInstance.connect(addr1)
await lotteryConnectedToSigner.buyLottery(1,{value: ethers.utils.parseEther('1')});
const userTickets = await lotteryConnectedToSigner.getLooteryID(0,addr1.address);
const length = lotteryConnectedToSigner.getLength(addr1.address)
             expect(length).equal(1);
             expect(userTickets[0].looteryID).equal(1);
            });
```

Also you can get all of mapping data using one function and get details after calling function, here to simplify i prefer using 2 separate functions to get `looteryID` and `length`.